# Center a TextBlock inside a ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: layout, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I have the following XAML code:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="GameList" Margin="12" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,5" Height="67" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

But I couldn't set textblock centered  (vertically and horizontally).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

The first solution is to specify the ListBox's `ItemContainerStyle` **inside** the ListBox and set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Center`.

```xml
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The second solution is to define a **style**, and apply the style to the ListBox (so it's reusable).

```xml
<Style x:Key="ListBoxCenteredItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">                       
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>                    
</Style>

<ListBox 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxCenteredItemStyle}"/>
```

The `ItemTemplate` of a ListBox is just a DataTemplate for displaying each data item. If there is a need to style a single row, the `ItemContainerStyle` is the guy. :)